# WPF Window controls not appearing

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm making a WPF application, and when I call `Show()` on one of my windows the actual contents of the window don't show up. The title bar is shown but the rest is blank.  I want to open the window (which contains only a label that says "Connecting...") and then continue with my program.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    getPort()
    connect()
    updateData()
End Sub

Private Sub getPort()
    Dim myChooseCom As New ChooseCOM
    myChooseCom.ShowDialog()
    myChooseCom = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub connect()
    Me.Hide()
    Dim connectWindow As New ConnectWait
    connectWindow.Show()
    connectSerial(SerialName)
    connectWindow.Close()
    Me.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub connectSerial(port As String)
    Try
        SerialPort.PortName = port
        SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        SerialPort.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message + "Verify that the Bluetooth device is on.")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

`getPort()` runs and creates a ChooseCOM window, which has all the controls displaying normally. ChooseCOM sets SerialName, which is a global. Then, `connect()` hides the main window and I open a ConnectWait window, which is just a form with a label that says "Connecting...". I'd like this window to be open while `connectSerial()` runs because `SerialPort.Open()` takes a few seconds and I would rather the user know that the program is still active and connecting to the serial port. However, the "Connecting..." label is never shown and the `connectWindow` stays blank until it is closed. How can I force the window to load completely before continuing?

Comment: What does your `ConnectWait` window look like? What happens if you remove all this code and just call `Show` on the window in the `Loaded` event of the main window?

Comment: ConnnectWait is a window that only contains a single control, a label that says "Connecting...". If I call `Show` on it from the main window's `Loaded` event then it displays the label correctly.

Comment: After working more on this, I found something very confusing. Calling `Show` works in the main `Loaded` event, but only before the call to `getPort()`. I set a breakpoint at the first line of the `Loaded` function and followed line by line. If I put `connectWindow.Show()` before `getPort()`, the label shows as soon as I step past the call to `Show`. If I put it after, then once I step past that line it just brings up the empty window with no label showing. Also, in the original program I can't exit the window once it is open, which makes me think it's somehow frozen in the middle of loading.

Comment: Strange... it can have something to do with the code opening the serial port, because that is running on the main thread, so it's possible that the window can't do anything (even redraw) until the method is finished. After which the window is closed anyway. You might want to move that to a background thread. Also your `getPort` method opens another window as dialog - does that work?

Comment: Yeah, `ShowDialog` displays correctly. Also, if I call `Show` and then after that open a new window with `ShowDialog` then both windows display correctly.